# Force postgres_fdw to use password?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have two databases set up as part of the same Postgresql 9.4 database cluster, and I'm trying to access a table in one of them from the other using a postgres_fdw. I have it all set up and working as a superuser, however when I try to access the foreign table as a normal user, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superuser cannot connect if the server does not request a password.
HINT:  Target server's authentication method must be changed.
```

Now I understand that this is because I have the server set up with trust authentication for certain subnets, including Its own. However, in the 1 `USER MAPPING` I created, I did specify a password, with the hope that doing so would force it to use password authentication. No such luck apparently.

As such, my question is if there is any way around this somewhat onerous requirement? Is there a way to force this connection, or a specific user, or the like to use password authentication? Or some way to disable the requirement? Or is my only option to change the configuration to require passwords, and deal with whatever that breaks?

Comment: Yes, [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) allows different authentication rules for specific users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nick Barnes pointed out in a comment, pg_hba allows different authentication rules for specific users. As such, the solution to this issue was to simply create a user specifically for these FDW connections, and set that user in the pg_hba.conf to require a password. That way my trusted web apps on the trusted network can continue connecting as usual, but the FDW can get the password request it requires.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force FDW to use a password: the server on the other end must request the password. the usual default for local socket connections is no password.

Try connecting via TCP instead of using local sockets: add `host=localhost` to the connection parameters, that will usually fix it.